# Expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gcc, inline-assembly

I am getting `Expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant` error in [mach_override.c](http://scplugin.tigris.org/svn/scplugin/trunk/SCFinderPlugin/mach_override.c) in [scplugin project](http://scplugin.tigris.org/svn/scplugin/trunk/) on the second line of below code.

```
asm(        
            ".text;"
            ".align 2, 0x90;"
            ".globl _atomic_mov64;"
            "_atomic_mov64:;"
            "   pushl %ebp;"
            "   movl %esp, %ebp;"
            "   pushl %esi;"
            "   pushl %ebx;"
            "   pushl %ecx;"
            "   pushl %eax;"
            "   pushl %edx;"

            // atomic push of value to an address
            // we use cmpxchg8b, which compares content of an address with 
            // edx:eax. If they are equal, it atomically puts 64bit value 
            // ecx:ebx in address. 
            // We thus put contents of address in edx:eax to force ecx:ebx
            // in address
            "   mov     8(%ebp), %esi;"  // esi contains target address
            "   mov     12(%ebp), %ebx;"
            "   mov     16(%ebp), %ecx;" // ecx:ebx now contains value to put in target address
            "   mov     (%esi), %eax;"
            "   mov     4(%esi), %edx;"  // edx:eax now contains value currently contained in target address
            "   lock; cmpxchg8b (%esi);" // atomic move.

            // restore registers
            "   popl %edx;"
            "   popl %eax;"
            "   popl %ecx;"
            "   popl %ebx;"
            "   popl %esi;"
            "   popl %ebp;"
            "   ret"
);
```

`Allow asm, inline typeof` flag is set in my build setting. can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following change ( in the flags):

```
C language dialect = Compiler Default
```